# Java FX slider dynamic change of grid

Tags: java, dynamic, javafx, grid, slider

I made a class that creates a grid with parameters in constructor. However, I would like to **change** the **number of lines** (or size) of the grid **with a slider**. I managed to create a slider that prints the values to console. Now I would like to assign the values from slider to change the grid but it doesn't work. Here is the main class.

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane root = new Pane();
    final Slider sliderSize = new Slider(0, 20, 5);
    sliderSize.setShowTickMarks(true);
    sliderSize.setShowTickLabels(true);
    sliderSize.setMajorTickUnit(5);
    root.getChildren().add(sliderSize);

    sliderSize.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                Number old_val, Number new_val) {
            Grid a = new Grid(root, 100, 100, 10, (int) new_val);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Grid");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

And here is the Grid class.

```
public class Grid {

public Grid(Pane root, int xp, int yp, int width, int numberOfLines) {


    for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfLines; j++) {


        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(xp);
        line.setStartY(yp + width * j);
        line.setEndX(xp + width * numberOfLines);
        line.setEndY(yp + width * j);
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        root.getChildren().add(line);

    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfLines; j++) {


        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(xp + width * j);
        line.setStartY(yp);
        line.setEndX(xp + width * j);
        line.setEndY(yp + width * numberOfLines);
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        root.getChildren().add(line);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Your Grid class adds lines, but never removes the previous set of lines.  Perhaps it should do `root.getChildren().removeIf(c -> c instanceof Line);` first.